# Problems with MediaExtractor

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I am trying to get specific frames at specific times as images from a movie using `MediaExtractor` and `MediaCodec`. I can do it successfully if:

- I use `extractor.seekTo(time, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC);` , however, this only gives the nearest sync frame not the target frame.
- I sequentially extract all frames using `extractor.advance();` , but I need to get the target frame not all.

So, I try the following:

```
extractor.seekTo(time, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC);
while(extractor.getSampleTime()<time /*target time*/) extractor.advance();
```

This provides the correct frame, but for some reason the image is corrupted. It looks like the correct image (the one I get from the successful cases), but with some pixelation and a strange haze.

The `while-loop` is the only thing that is different between the successful cases and the corrupted ones. What to do to advance `MediaExtractor` to a specific time (not just sync time) without getting a corrupted image?

Comment: Are you passing all of the frames to the decoder in your `while` loop, or just extracting the target frame and handing that to the decoder?  (i.e. are you handing a P-frame to the decoder?)

Comment: @fadden Thank you for always being there for MediaCodec questions :) I loop as stated in the question until extractor is at the target time and then pass extractor.readSampleData() to feed the decoder. To be honest, I don't know what is a P-frame

Comment: Basically, I initially use extractor.advance(); to get all the times, then pass these times to a custom adapter. The getView() of this adapter takes the time, pass it the while loop stated to set the extractor to the time I got from the adapter, then pass this time to MediaCodec to extract the frame at that time

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types .  Each frame isn't compressed individually, so you have to start decoding from an I-frame.  As far as I can tell, the terms "I frame", "key frame", and "sync frame" are used somewhat interchangeably.  So I believe you have to start decoding from the nearest sync frame.

Comment: @fadden Hi, I am trying to feed the extractor output to MediaMuxer, however, it fails at muxer.stop(). I check your answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505845/mediamuxer-error-failed-to-stop-the-muxer) question, however, I am sure both Video and Audio tracks have "csd-0" field (I try to use extractor to feed both video and audio to the Muxer with same formats received from extractor)

Comment: Create a new question here with the logcat output.  `MediaMuxer` spits out a bunch of stuff when `close()` is called; show that and any exception that was thrown.  A short snippet showing how you're feeding the muxer would also be useful.

Comment: I submitted a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341169/mediamuxer-fails-to-stop-if-csd-1-not-exist)

Comment: Before I ask a new question - should this technique (grabbing the closest previous sync frame to your desired time and running the encoder forward from there) perform well enough to do real-time scrubbing back and forth through a video?  I'm seeing terrible lag, so just wanting to clarify if I'm expecting too much. :)  If this should work, I'll open a new question to discuss.  Thanks!

Comment: For me, A frame can take 500 - 1000 ms for an 1080p video (including seeking, decoding and conversion to Bitmap). I think I can enhance more by reducing GCs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to fadden comment, I have to keep feeding the encoder since the `I-frame` has the full picture and the `P` and `B` frames have differences (this is how compression is achieved). So I need to start with an `I-frame` (it was same as sync frame) and keep feeding the other frames to the decoder to receive the full image.

Comment: I'm facing the [same kind of situation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660469/copy-consecutive-frames-from-video). How do you get the specific time in the first place? Because I'm using a similar solution, but I never get the expected frame. I suspect the time I receive from the video view is not accurate, or my while loop is not working right.

Comment: Could you give more details about how you "keep feeding" it from the I-frame until you reach the frame you want?

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah: Would MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC seek video to I frame? and how exactly do you keep feeding from I Frame?

Comment: Yes it does. I keep feeding using extractor.advance() to get the following P/B frame.