# Android: How to use MediaMuxer with video/mp4v-es instead of video/avc?

Tags: android, video-encoding, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I want to be able to use mp4v-es instead of avc on some devices. The encoder runs fine using avc, but when I replace it with mp4v-es, the muxer reports:

```
E/MPEG4Writer(12517): Missing codec specific data
```

as in [MediaMuxer error "Failed to stop the muxer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505845/mediamuxer-error-failed-to-stop-the-muxer), and the video cannot be played. The difference is that I am adding the correct track/format to the muxer, without receiving any error:

```
...else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
           MediaFormat newFormat = encoder.getOutputFormat();
           mTrackIndex[encID] = mMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
```

Is there any difference in handling mp4v-es compared to avc? One mention, I just skip "bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG" when it occurs, as for avc it was not needed.Thanks.

Comment: Does newFormat have csd-0 and csd-1?

Comment: @Marlon: the newFormat is: {height=720, mime=video/mp4v-es, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=30,capacity=30], what=1869968451, width=1280} and csd-0: 000001B006000001B58913000001000000012000C48881F4528045A1463F. csd-1 is not present, but I think it appears only for H264.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341169/mediamuxer-fails-to-stop-if-csd-1-not-exist   it looks like csd-1 could be required

Comment: From an `encoder` to `MPEG4Writer`, I don't think it is mandatory to have 2 buffers for `csd`. `MPEG4Writer` can handle only one buffer. The error i.e. `Missing codec specific data` comes when there is no `CSD`. For `video/mp4v-es` i.e. `MPEG4` video elementary stream, the `MPEG4Writer` expects the data to be packaged as `ESDS` format as compared to `AVCC` as here: http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Writer.cpp#1466

Comment: The `csd` is read when a new `Track` is created (Ref: `MPEG4Writer.cpp` above, line no.1370). For the track, video encoder is the source and hence, your encoder should support `getFormat` in which the data should be packaged in `ESDS` format.

Comment: @Ganesh: Please elaborate it as an answer, with some emphasis on packaging mpeg4 header data in ESDS format, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Ganesh: MediaFormat has a method, setByteBuffer("csd-0",..). If I understood your comment correctly, in the case that the encoder returns mpeg4 elementary video bitstream for headers(as it does), this elementary bitstream should be packaged as ESDS, written back to csd-0 with the method above, and then the MediaFormat object provided to addTrack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as Ganesh pointed out, unfortunately it does seem that this isn't possible right now, without modifying the platform source.

There's actually two ways that the codec specific data can be passed to the internal MPEG4Writer class, but neither of them actually work without modifications.

As Ganesh found, the logic for remapping MediaFormat keys to the internal format seems to be missing handling of codec specific data for any other video codec than H264. A tested modification that fixes this issue is as follows:

```
diff --git a/media/libstagefright/Utils.cpp b/media/libstagefright/Utils.cpp
index 25afc5b..304fe59 100644
--- a/media/libstagefright/Utils.cpp
+++ b/media/libstagefright/Utils.cpp
@@ -549,14 +549,14 @@ void convertMessageToMetaData(const sp<AMessage> &msg, sp<MetaData> &meta) {
     // reassemble the csd data into its original form
     sp<ABuffer> csd0;
     if (msg->findBuffer("csd-0", &csd0)) {
-        if (mime.startsWith("video/")) { // do we need to be stricter than this?
+        if (mime == MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC) {
             sp<ABuffer> csd1;
             if (msg->findBuffer("csd-1", &csd1)) {
                 char avcc[1024]; // that oughta be enough, right?
                 size_t outsize = reassembleAVCC(csd0, csd1, avcc);
                 meta->setData(kKeyAVCC, kKeyAVCC, avcc, outsize);
             }
-        } else if (mime.startsWith("audio/")) {
+        } else if (mime == MEDIA_MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AAC || mime == MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_MPEG4) {
             int csd0size = csd0->size();
             char esds[csd0size + 31];
             reassembleESDS(csd0, esds);
```

Secondly, instead of passing the codec specific data as `csd-0` in MediaFormat, you could in principle pass the same buffer (with the `MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG` flag set) to `MediaMuxer.writeSampleData`. This approach doesn't work currently since this method doesn't check for the codec config flag at all - it could be fixed with this modification:

```
diff --git a/media/libstagefright/MediaMuxer.cpp b/media/libstagefright/MediaMuxer.cpp
index c7c6f34..d612e01 100644
--- a/media/libstagefright/MediaMuxer.cpp
+++ b/media/libstagefright/MediaMuxer.cpp
@@ -193,6 +193,9 @@ status_t MediaMuxer::writeSampleData(const sp<ABuffer> &buffer, size_t trackInde
     if (flags & MediaCodec::BUFFER_FLAG_SYNCFRAME) {
         sampleMetaData->setInt32(kKeyIsSyncFrame, true);
     }
+    if (flags & MediaCodec::BUFFER_FLAG_CODECCONFIG) {
+        sampleMetaData->setInt32(kKeyIsCodecConfig, true);
+    }

     sp<MediaAdapter> currentTrack = mTrackList[trackIndex];
     // This pushBuffer will wait until the mediaBuffer is consumed.
```

As far as I can see, there's no way to mux MPEG4 video with MediaMuxer right now while using the public API, without modifying the platform source. Given the issues in Utils.cpp above, you can't mux any video format that requires codec specific data, except for H264. If VP8 is an option, you can mux that into webm files (together with vorbis audio), but hardware encoders for VP8 is probably much less common than hardware encoders for MPEG4.

Comment: This issue has been reported upstream at http://b.android.com/90138, and a fix has been submitted at https://android-review.googlesource.com/120945.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue and fixing the same into mainstream tree.

Comment: Well, the fix hasn't been merged yet. I actually found 2 different changes awaiting review that do almost the same, that have been submitted by other people (seemingly unrelated to this post here) but that nobody have merged or even commented on yet.

Comment: Well.. we will have to contact Google experts on this. I am not sure if the same has already been integrated into an internal tree.

Comment: My fix at least merges cleanly into their internal tree (according to the buildbot a few days ago), so I don't think they have got any fix for it yet. But often it can take a few months before they react to patches sent via the review system.

Comment: Well.. let's hope for the best. I will keep following up on this solution through your bug and Gerrit patch.

Comment: My fix in https://android-review.googlesource.com/120945 has now been merged in AOSP master, so it will hopefully be part of the next major release.

Comment: Good job Martin... It is very good to have the change inside AOSP... Great follow-up...

Comment: Your change has been tagged for `android-m-preview`.. please check: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+log/1d82e69dffe9214fd35d0ec75ce9b957da7fc50b

Answer (score 2):

I presume you have the ability to modify the `Stagefright` sources and hence, I have a proposed solution for your problem, but one which requires a customization.

**Background:**

When an `encoder` completes encoding, the first buffer will have the `csd` information which is usually tagged with `OMX_BUFFERFLAG_CODECCONFIG` flag. When such a buffer is returned to the `MediaCodec`, it shall store the same as `csd-0` in [`MediaCodec::amendOutputFormatWithCodecSpecificData`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaCodec.cpp#2191).

**Now**, when this buffer is given to `MediaMuxer`, the same is processed as part of `addTrack`,in which [`convertMessageToMetadata`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaMuxer.cpp#94) is invoked. If you refer to the implementation of the same, we can observe that only `AVC` is handled for `video` and defaults to `audio` for `ESDS` creation.

**EDIT:**

Here, my recommendation is to modify this [line](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/Utils.cpp#559) as below and try your experiment

```
} 
if (mime.startsWith("audio/") || (!strcmp(mime, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_MPEG4)) {
```

With this change, I feel it should work for `MPEG4` video track also. The change is to convert the `else if` into `if` as the previous check for `video` will also try to process the data, but only for `AVC`.

Comment: Won't code at line 552: "if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {" get all video buffers? Anyway, I would need to be able to export mp4v-es using MediaCodec public API (so I can manipulate buffer contents as needed) but not resort on jni and native code.

Comment: @user1592546..Yes you are right. We can overcome this by removing the `else` in `else if` so that there are 2 checks. To optimize this, for the first `video` check, we could add another part to verify if the `MIME` type is `AVC` or not. Please see my edited answer above.

Comment: I'll accept mstorsjo's answer, for completeness, further reference, and providing the link to full solution. Anyway, this answer provided more insight to the issue, and is appreciated.

Comment: @user1592546.. This is fine. I am happy that your problem is solved.

Comment: Well, it still does not work the way I want :) i.e. only java side coding, but I have to accept that.