# Android MediaCodec backward seeking

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, seek, mediaextractor, grafika

I'm trying to implement precise seeking for video using `MediaCodec` and `MediaExtractor`. By following Grafika's [MoviePlayer](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/MoviePlayer.java), I've managed to implement the forward seeking. However I'm still having problem with backward seeking. The relevant bit of code is here:

```
public void seekBackward(long position){
    final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 10000;
    int inputChunk = 0;
    long firstInputTimeNsec = -1;

    boolean outputDone = false;
    boolean inputDone = false;

    mExtractor.seekTo(position, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC);
    Log.d("TEST_MEDIA", "sampleTime: " + mExtractor.getSampleTime()/1000 + " -- position: " + position/1000 + " ----- BACKWARD");

    while (mExtractor.getSampleTime() < position && position >= 0) {

        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "loop");
        if (mIsStopRequested) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Stop requested");
            return;
        }

        // Feed more data to the decoder.
        if (!inputDone) {
            int inputBufIndex = mDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
            if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                if (firstInputTimeNsec == -1) {
                    firstInputTimeNsec = System.nanoTime();
                }
                ByteBuffer inputBuf = mDecoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
                // Read the sample data into the ByteBuffer.  This neither respects nor
                // updates inputBuf's position, limit, etc.
                int chunkSize = mExtractor.readSampleData(inputBuf, 0);
                if (chunkSize < 0) {
                    // End of stream -- send empty frame with EOS flag set.
                    mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 0, 0L,
                            MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                    inputDone = true;
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "sent input EOS");
                } else {
                    if (mExtractor.getSampleTrackIndex() != mTrackIndex) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "WEIRD: got sample from track " +
                                mExtractor.getSampleTrackIndex() + ", expected " + mTrackIndex);
                    }
                    long presentationTimeUs = mExtractor.getSampleTime();
                    mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, chunkSize,
                            presentationTimeUs, 0 /*flags*/);
                    if (VERBOSE) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "submitted frame " + inputChunk + " to dec, size=" + chunkSize);
                    }
                    inputChunk++;
                    mExtractor.advance();
                }
            } else {
                if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "input buffer not available");
            }
        }

        if (!outputDone) {
            int decoderStatus = mDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
            if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                // no output available yet
                if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "no output from decoder available");
            } else if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                // not important for us, since we're using Surface
                if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "decoder output buffers changed");
            } else if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                MediaFormat newFormat = mDecoder.getOutputFormat();
                if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "decoder output format changed: " + newFormat);
            } else if (decoderStatus < 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "unexpected result from decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " +
                                decoderStatus);
            } else { // decoderStatus >= 0
                if (firstInputTimeNsec != 0) {
                    // Log the delay from the first buffer of input to the first buffer
                    // of output.
                    long nowNsec = System.nanoTime();
                    Log.d(TAG, "startup lag " + ((nowNsec-firstInputTimeNsec) / 1000000.0) + " ms");
                    firstInputTimeNsec = 0;
                }
                boolean doLoop = false;
                if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "surface decoder given buffer " + decoderStatus +
                        " (size=" + mBufferInfo.size + ")");
                if ((mBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "output EOS");
                    if (mLoop) {
                        doLoop = true;
                    } else {
                        outputDone = true;
                    }
                }

                boolean doRender = (mBufferInfo.size != 0);

                // As soon as we call releaseOutputBuffer, the buffer will be forwarded
                // to SurfaceTexture to convert to a texture.  We can't control when it
                // appears on-screen, but we can manage the pace at which we release
                // the buffers.
                if (doRender && mFrameCallback != null) {
                    mFrameCallback.preRender(mBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs);
                }
                mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, doRender);
                doRender = false;
                if (doRender && mFrameCallback != null) {
                    mFrameCallback.postRender();
                }

                if (doLoop) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Reached EOS, looping");
                    mExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
                    inputDone = false;
                    mDecoder.flush();    // reset decoder state
                    mFrameCallback.loopReset();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, it's the same as MoviePlayer's `doExtract` method. I just add a slight modification to seek back to the previous keyframe than decode forward to the position I want. I've also follow fadden's [suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31322473/1602807) with little success.

Another side question, to my understanding, ExoPlayer is built upon `MediaCodec`, then how come it can play videos recorded by iOS just fine while MoviePlayer's pure implementation of `MediaCodec` can't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this is how I solve my problem, basically I misunderstood fadden's comment on the `render` flag. The problem is not with the decoding but instead only displaying the last buffer that is closest to the seeking position. Here is how I do it:

```
if (Math.abs(position - mExtractor.getSampleTime()) < 10000) {
   mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, true);
} else {
   mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, false);
}
```

This is quite a hackish way to go about this. The elegant way should be saving the last output buffer and display it outside the `while` loop but I don't really know how to access the output buffer so that I can save it to a temporary one.

**EDIT:**

This is a bit less hackish way to do this. Basically, we only need to calculate the total frames in between the keyframe and the seeking position and then we just need to display 1 or 2 frames closest to the seeking position. Something like this:

```
    mExtractor.seekTo(position, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC);
    int stopPosition = getStopPosition(mExtractor.getSampleTime(), position);
    int count = 0;

    while (mExtractor.getSampleTime() < position && mExtractor.getSampleTime() != -1 && position >= 0) {
    ....

        if(stopPosition - count < 2) { //just to make sure we will get something (1 frame sooner), see getStopPosition comment
           mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, true);
        }else{
           mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, false);
        }
        count++;
     ...
    }

/**
 * Calculate how many frame in between the key frame and the seeking position
 * so that we can determine how many while loop will be execute, then we can just
 * need to stop the loop 2 or 3 frames sooner to ensure we can get something.
 * */
private int getStopPosition(long start, long end){
    long delta = end - start;
    float framePerMicroSecond = mFPS / 1000000;

    return (int)(delta * framePerMicroSecond);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it seems that just `releaseOutputBuffer` would lead to another problem if you did not feed more data via `dequeueOutputBuffer`. I got `MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xfffffff3` with your code. And could you show how you calculated your fps? I had tried `exceptor.getSampleTime / 1_000_000f`, but can't get correct fps. Thanks again.